# TypeScript class decorator get class name

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the name of a class at runtime (minified!) in a class decorator.

When I do this:

`const metadata = Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', target.constructor);`

I get undefined. I need to know the class name and not the minified value. I thought that TSC would write the metadata information about the name of the class, but I can't find any evidence about this.

I have

`"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,`

set

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Richard no unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for the nameof operator, which unfortunately isn't implemented (yet):
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579